# Java compare size of files

Tags: java, file, methods, size

I dont get why the value of diffSize is never used

here is my method:

```
public static long diffSize(String File01, String File02){
    //get path to first file
    File file = new File(File01);
    //get path to second file
    File file2 = new File(File02);

    //get size of first file
    long bytes = file.length();
    //get size of second file
    long bytes2 = file2.length();

    //get difference
    return bytes-bytes2;
}
```

here is the line I used to call the method in my Main

`extensions.diffSize("C:\\Users\\katra\\IdeaProjects\\MP1.1\\references\\epfl.png","C:\\Users\\katra\\IdeaProjects\\MP1.1\\references\\epfl.qoi" );`

and in the terminal nothing is returned

Comment: The method returns a result, where is it used / printed to console?

Comment: You use the name of the class it is  coded in, or if it is in scope you can simply call it with no reference to the class. This is better than answering your question  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-method-in-java-with-examples/   and here's another for that problem  https://www.javatpoint.com/static-function-in-java   note you can pass non static arguments into a static method but not obtain them any other way.